# I have Quantity of item sold of a Brand and its competitor stored in the same column but want it in seperate column

Tags: google-bigquery, data-analysis

I have a table given in the following format:

| Store_Id | Category | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brand_A | 3 |
| 1 | Brand_A_Competitor | 4 |
| 1 | Brand_B | 5 |
| 1 | Brand_B_Competitor | 6 |
| 2 | Brand_A | 8 |
| 2 | Brand_A_Competitor | 4 |
| 2 | Brand_B | 7 |
| 2 | Brand_B_Competitor | 9 |

Here, the brand and its competitor are present in the same column. What I need them to be is in a separate column as shown below:

| Store_Id | Category | Comp_Brand | Quantity | Competitor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brand_A | Brand_A_Competitor | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | Brand_B | Brand_B_Competitor | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | Brand_A | Brand_A_Competitor | 8 | 4 |
| 2 | Brand_B | Brand_B_Competitor | 7 | 9 |

Can someone help me with the query for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself, with one side of the join for brand and the other side for the competitor.

```
select
  a.Store_Id,
  a.Category,
  b.Category Comp_Brand,
  a.Quantity,
  b.Quantity Competitor
from mytable a
left join mytable b on b.Store_Id = a.Store_Id
  and b.Category = a.Category || '_Competitor'
where a.Category not like '%_Competitor'
order by a.Store_Id, a.Category
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select Store_Id, 
  replace(Category, '_Competitor', '') as Category, 
  replace(Category, '_Competitor', '') || '_Competitor' as Comp_Brand, 
  max(if(Category like '%_Competitor', null, Quantity)) as Quantity,
  max(if(Category like '%_Competitor', Quantity, null)) as Competitor,
from `project.dataset.table`
group by Store_Id, Category, Comp_Brand
```

If to apply to sample data from your question  output is

[image]